# How to set a session variable in JavaScript and access it in ASP.NET .cs file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session

I want to set a session variable in JavaScript and call page reload. And at this point I want the aspx.cs file to recognize the change in session variable and make appropriate changes to the webpage. I've tried using :

**Assigning the ASP.NET Session Variable using Javascript:**

```
function SetUserName()
{
    var userName = "Shekhar Shete";
    '<%Session["UserName"] = "' + userName + '"; %>';
     alert('<%=Session["UserName"] %>');
}
</script>
```

**Accessing ASP.NET Session variable using Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetUserName()
    {

        var username = '<%= Session["UserName"] %>';
        alert(username );
    }
</script>
```

Although the session variable is set. And if I reload the page the JS field recognizes the new data for the session variable. It's not being recognized in the aspx.cs file.

Basically I'm trying to send data to my aspx.cs file based on user actions on the webpage.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you provide the ASP code (the code enclosed in *<% %>*) is processed before the page goes to the browser, the Javascript is processed a the browser.

If you want to pass back a value to the server there are a number of options, but one easy way would be to use a hidden input ([example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden)) inside a form, and submit back to server, and then when you get the post back on the server you add it to the session.

```
void Page_Load() {
    //Don't blindly trust input from the client, validate first!
    Session["Username"] = Request.Params["Username"];
}
```

Comment: My VS is throwing an error for this Request.Params("Username");. Says don't user params as a method.

Comment: My apologies, it should be Request.Params["Username"], I'll update the answer.